# How can the initialization of a struct be used as variable in a function call. ANSI-C Version

Tags: c, function, struct, c89, ansi-c

I am writing C89, C90, Ansi-C Code. One of my functions requires a struct as a parameter. I want to call the function with the initialization of that struct rather than creating a struct first then passing it to the function.

Here are some snippets which work.

```
typedef struct {
    char* EventName;
    char* Message; 
} Event;

Event myEvent = {
    .EventName = "infomessage", 
    .Message = "Testmessage"
};

Notify(myEvent);
```

and here is what I would like to write but which doesn't work:

```
Notify({.EventName = "infomessage", .Message = "Testmessage"});
```

or even better

```
Notify({"infomessage", "Testmessage"});
```

EDIT: LabCVI is using the ISO 9899:1990 standard.

Comment: btw: most people mean ANSI-C89 when they say ANSI-C, wich is equivalent to ISO-C90; similarly, ISO-C99 is equivalent to ANSI-C2000; the only place where I have ever heard anyone refer to C99 as ANSI-C is here on SO

Comment: Ah, could be newbie mistake - but all "modern" Ansi-C books i've read refer to C99,... those books are in german so maybe its a regional thing. The IDE i am using is LabCVI 2010 - i thought it is C99 because it understands the ++ operator and the component initialisation for structs.

Comment: The `++` operator was in C89

Comment: That way of initializing, `{ .member = 0 }`, is new in C99, and is a syntax error in C90. Use the older, `Event myEvent = { "infomessage", "Testmessage" };`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the compound literal `(Event){"infomessage", "Testmessage"}`, ie

```
Notify((Event){"infomessage", "Testmessage"});
```

Comment: @Johannes: according to http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/8764 , LabWindows/CVI doesn't support compound literals; incidentally, they also use the term ANSI C99

Comment: Interesting - C99 supports compound literals, but the LabCVI help only refers to the C90 standard wich doesn't support compound literals. So the answer is right for C99 and above but it is impossible for everything below that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, as that would be mixing declarations and code. Also,

> warning: compound literals are a C99-specific feature [-Wc99-extensions]

In C90, one way is to just give it a temporary name, like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Event { char *EventName, *Message; };

static void Notify(const struct Event e)
    { printf("%s: %s\n", e.EventName, e.Message); }

int main(void) {
    struct Event myEvent = { "infomessage", "Testmessage" };
    Notify(myEvent);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Notice the older `{ data1, data2 }` method of initialization.

If you are worried about scope, enclosing it in braces with the initialization at the top is also possible.